# Windows EC2 instance cannot be reached via HTTP/HTTPS but RDP works

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-ec2

VPC and Subnet => Public and has an Internet Gateway
I've Apache web server running on the instance listening on port 80 & 443 and I can reach it from within the ec2 instance.
VPC and Subnet NACL is set to default and allows all network.
Instance has a public DNS
I can RDP into the instance from my local.
Instance can reach the internet
I cannot reach the instance via my local on browser or telnet on port 80/443

Do you guys have any idea what's causing it?

I've verified that the subnet is public, has an internet gateway, NACL's good and I can RDP into the server. The instance can access the internet.

Edit: Security Group on the Instance allows all ports from my IP address.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about the security group assigned to the EC2 instance, so that is probably what you are missing.

Comment: Depending on the version of Windows you might also need to set the local firewall to allow incoming traffic on the relevant ports (if you haven't disabled the local firewall) but Mark's suggestion regarding Security Groups is the first place to look

Comment: What is the configuration of the **Security Group** associated with the EC2 instance?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I've updated the question with the security group status - it allows all ports from my IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the windows firewall settings. I had to allow ports 80 and 443 to go through.
Thanks to Steve G in the question comments for the answer.